# How to phrase my subjective question to avoid unconstructive answers

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Often, I face myself asking a tricky question where someone interested in giving me a constructive answer would have to sit down and **think**. They would also need to **care** about my question and my problem and be **open-minded** (which is the whole idea behind [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)). Instead, they often end up just trying to make a point - the point they may have had all their lives and they wouldn't reconsider - or make me bad or show off their (sometimes questionable) knowledge. In short: useless and not constructive.

Usually, this doesn't happen when the question itself is technical and can be answered very objectively (as on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)). But as soon as I'd like a subjective, critical but constructive answer, I get a bashing. And even more so, the bashers get voted up by other bashers such that the really constructive, interesting answers will move down in ranking among all the answers.

Is there a way to circumvent that? E.g. in phrasing my question very carefully (how?) Any ideas welcome.

NOTE: I've already asked the question here: [How to phrase my subjective question to avoid unconstructive answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71977/how-to-phrase-my-subjective-question-to-avoid-unconstructive-answers), but **meta.programmers** is the better place for it than **meta.stackoverflow**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most important factor in getting constructive answers, by a wide margin, is to ask the question constructively in the first place.  For example, I'm looking at one of your questions, which goes:

> **Would anyone care about a database-mapping tool, that's not really an ORM?**
>
> I still find it hard to believe that most Java persistence tools and standards try to somehow implement an object-relational model...
>
> [...]
>
> In short, they're still in Vietnam as qstarin put it in his answer.
>
> [...]

And so on and so forth.  The problem is that **this question is written as a rant**, quoting an editorial that's four-and-a-half years old, to boot; you appear to be upset that more people aren't using your software.  That's fine, but you have to approach it from a neutral perspective if you don't want combative answers.

Personally, I don't even think you should have asked the question, because the motivation is a little suspect.  But assuming people can get past that, I might have worded it like so:

> **Is jOOQ a viable model for querying databases?**
>
> As the creator and maintainer of the jOOQ tool, I've often felt that an object-oriented query model has several advantages over a more traditional ORM, such as:
>
> [blah blah blah]
>
> However, I'm not sure how many others share my enthusiasm.  So I was wondering if anyone can point me to some *disadvantages* of using this approach?  Are there issues that I am overlooking, either conceptual or practical?  Is there anything that I could add or change to make this more attractive to developers?

This *still* sounds a little like self-promotion but at least you're not subtly insinuating that everybody else is doing it wrong.  *That's* why you got the answers you did.

---

Now, that said, if you are *absolutely certain* that the question itself is constructive, then the best way to get constructive answers is to ask specifically for them:

> [Question text]
>
> ---
>
> ## Please answer constructively.
>
> I realize that many people have strong feelings on the subject of ORMs and similar subjects, and that is fine, but please **explain** your answers, giving specific examples from your own experience if possible.  Constructive criticism is welcome, but please be specific!

Comment: Hi Aaronaught. Thanks for the honest answer. You are right. From how you put it, I couldn't agree more. And you actually analysed the topic I was concerned with. I do realise now that my question could be seen as a rant itself, I hadn't thought of that.